# Dataiku - Saving Models in DSS Python Receipes

Tags: scikit-learn, dataiku

How do I save a model in Dataiku?

This is the tutorial that I am using: https://doc.dataiku.com/dss/latest/python-api/model-evaluation-stores.html

Example Code:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
m = dataiku.Model(reg)

> TypeError: argument of type 'LinearRegression' is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but `dataiku.Model(...)` expects the param to be a `str` that corresponds to the id of the model according to [the doc](https://doc.dataiku.com/dss/latest/python-api/saved_models.html).

You might either want to:

- Turn your linear regression into a mlflow model and import it in Dataiku DSS.
- Use the auto ML pipeline to train your linear regression in Dataiku

In both cases, the corresponding doc can be found here: [link](https://doc.dataiku.com/dss/latest/python-api/ml.html)